# Why does deployment of firebase project give me a path error?

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

trying to deploy project on firebase gives me the error below 
any ideas, Thanks for help

```
  sherif Folio $ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'plan2-plan2'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! path /home/sherif/functions/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/sherif/functions/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sherif/.npm/_logs/2018-04-28T22_14_49_737Z- 
debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero 
exit code254
```

Comment: the day before i was making a code lab for cloud actions i went through the code , seems i configured something i dont remember

Answer (score 2):

I also went through such problem and What I ended up doing was editing the firebase.json file and changed the preflight commands to be `npm --prefix ./functions run lint`. This seems to work on both Linux and Windows.

Initial code in file:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```